# Expected type `a' with `Double' error : Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm writing a program that returns a list of the k nearest neighbours, in distance order, according to metric d to point p in the list ps of points. All should be returned as proper neighbours if in the list ps are fewer than k elements. Also, two equally close points to p should be returned based on their initial order in the list ps

```
import Data.List

type Point a = (a,a)
type Metric a = (Point a) -> (Point a) -> Double

nearPoints ::  Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
nearPoints k d p [] = []
nearPoints k d p ps = take k (sortOn (pointsDistCalc p) ps)

pointsDistCalc :: Metric Double
pointsDistCalc (t1,t1) (t2,t2) = sqrt(((t1-t2)^2)+((t1-t2)^2))
```

This is the error message

```
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `Double'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          nearPoints :: forall a.
                        Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
      Expected type: Point Double
        Actual type: Point a
    * In the first argument of `pointsDistCalc', namely `p'
      In the first argument of `sortOn', namely `(pointsDistCalc p)'
      In the second argument of `take', namely
        `(sortOn (pointsDistCalc p) ps)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        ps :: [Point a]
        p :: Point a
        d :: Metric a
        nearPoints :: Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
11 | nearPoints k d p ps = take k (sortOn (pointsDistCalc p) ps)
```

Please can someone help me with this

Comment: You defined `pointsDiscCalc` as a `Metric` for `Point Double`s, hence that means that `nearPoints` which sort by that distance, should be `Point Double`s as well.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `pointsDistCalc` as a `Metric` for `Point Double`s, hence that means that `nearPoints` which sort by that distance, should be `Point Double`s as well.

That being said, the signature suggests that a metric is given, and thus that one does *not* per se uses the `PointsDistCalc`. You thus can implement this with:

```
nearPoints ::  Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
nearPoints _ _ _ [] = []
nearPoints k d p0 ps = take k (sortOn (d p0) ps)
```

There is no need to split the definition in two cases here: `sortOn` will return an empty list if it is given an empty list:

```
nearPoints ::  Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]
nearPoints k d p0 ps = take k (sortOn (d p0) ps)
```

Comment: I`m not sure when i compile it i get that Data.List does not export sortOn

Comment: it should work but it just says its not declared in its scope

Comment: @RobSam: what version do you use? `sortOn` is introduced since base 4.8 (ghc 7.10.1).

Comment: Thanks, i see that, but the issues is that the system to which i send this has a older version so i`ll have to use other sort method

Comment: mine is up to date

Comment: @RobSam: yes, I trhink you will have to implement your own version of `sortOn`.

Comment: i manged to to it another way

Comment: although its quite slow

Comment: @RobSam: `sortOn` is defined in terms of `sortBy` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sortOn

Comment: is there any way you could give some help on this issue? I will greatly appreciate